# jquery - why code always takes old value of textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a form with two textboxes for API Key and for stock ticker. Please find below the code.

```
<h1>Stock</h1>
<form id="frmGetComp">
    <p>API Key: <input type="text" id="txtAPI" value="" /></p>
    <p>Stock: <input type="text" id="txtStock" value="" /></p>
    <p><button id="btnCall">Call</button></p>
</form>
```

And below is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {                                     
            var stockId='';

            $("#txtStock").blur(function () {
                stockId= $(this).val();
                console.log(stockId);
            });

            $('#btnCall').click(function () {
                var apiKey = $('#txtAPI').val();

                stockId= $("#txtStock").val();
                console.log(':::call clicked:::', stockId);

                <assigning apikey statement> = apiKey;
                <stockId is passed in api call to fetch stock information>

                $('#frmGetComp').submit(false);
                $('#frmGetComp').reset = true;
                stockId= '';
                $('#txtStock').val('');

            });
        });
```

Now in this form when I enter information first time it retruns correct data. When I change the value of stock and click call button, every time it returns the stock information of first stock. It never takes new value entered in stock textbox.

**How do I get new value of stock textbox and get the information of that stock when call button is clicked ???**

Comment: remove blur function if do nothing,i checked your code and it work prefectly !!! http://jsfiddle.net/hm66s9su/

Comment: yes your code is working with no problem! => http://jsfiddle.net/o063orb2/

Comment: the code is not taking new value of textbox in api call.

Comment: its working for me :http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/o063orb2/1/